# Scrollbar inside table cell with norwap not working

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a container with a fixed width of 500px. Inside this table, there's a cell which may contain long text, and should be set to
`white-space: nowrap` so the long text appears all in one line. However once `nowrap` is set, the table changes the size to fit all the text and ignores the 500px width.

I would like for the table to keep the width of 500px and simply show the scroll inside the cell with the long text.

Here's my jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/aqd1c8tk/

Comment: I would argue, that this isn't the best UX/UI solution for your problem, but you know better what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention a maximum width for the table cell. Assuming your table width is 600px, cells maximum with could be 200px. After that, you can use `white-space: nowrap;`.

I have updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/faridv/bphydwmx/